# Frobenius for function algebras and tilting functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rigid-analytic-spaces

Consider for example a non archimedean field $K$, then one can take:
$$
 R = K\langle T^{\pm \frac{1}{p^\infty}}\rangle
$$
so in practice if I'm not wrong we' re taking:
$$
R \cong \varinjlim_{n}(K[ T^{ \frac{1}{p^n}}, T^{ -\frac{1}{p^n}}])^\wedge
$$
Now, not thinking so much to the formal definition (in which i'm not sure) in practice we're taking all the $p$-poter root of symbols $T$ and $T^{-1}$.

Clearly in the theory of perfectoids appears usually the tilting functor, so:
$$
 K^\flat := \varprojlim_{x \mapsto x^p}K/pK
$$
My question is: if I consider in the ring $K\langle T^{\pm \frac{1}{p^\infty}}\rangle$ and the series of Frobenius maps.
The tilt of $R$ is:
$$ 
 R^\flat \cong K^\flat\langle T^{\pm \frac{1}{p^\infty}}\rangle \hspace{0,5 cm}??
$$

Comment: Why would you expect the limit to change $K$ if all the maps are maps of $K$-algebars? The limit should just be $K\langle T^{\pm \frac{1}{p^\infty}}\rangle$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis yes of course I wrote something wrong, in fact I want to understand what is the tiltingof the all ring thanks for your answer... I realised the error just now

Comment: Then, this is true essentially by definition. Also, your definition of $K^\flat$ is wrong (do you mean the inverse limit over the monoids $K$ or do you want to replace $K$ by $K^\circ$ on the RHS and then invert a pseudo-uniformizer). Maybe you can try to work it out and let me/us know where you get stuck in proving this.